# How to style <select> and <option> with css ? It must be able to bind with angular

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

## HTML

Here is my code which i tried so far:

```
 <a href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/">bootstrap-select</a>, css works but i couldn't see any option value  in it
</p>
<select class=" tab-add-button tab-button bold pull-right" ng-model="teachingPlan.type" ng-options="type for type in ['Case Study','Project','Assignment','Quiz/Exam']" ng-change="assignmentTypeChange(teachingPlan)" >

<option value="" disabled > + Create Assessment</option>
</select>
```

Please help me regarding this

Comment: You can't reliably style `select` and `option` elements cross-browser using CSS. If you need to style them you're best to use a library to convert them to HTML, such as Select2

Comment: If you have `option` in your original `select` then the values will be definitely appended.. can you be more specific on your question?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ng-option will load its value but this custom js will not be able to bind  all of its value

Comment: Inspect the browser and see what all values get appended to the option..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I had tried it to. It will be able to show a option only, Other option are not appended

Comment: Then ng-option is not getting all the values..

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap select picker..

```
<script src="/js/Bootstrap/Select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had already tried this and this thing works with normal <select> and <option> tag but if we tried to use ng-option then it will not be able to bind